# jQuery Validation onfocusout error message for Radio & Checkbox

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-validate

With best of my knowledge i tried to use 'onfocusout' and it works fine. As mentioned on the site that 'onfocusout' will not work for Radio Group or Checkbox Group. So my question is if somehow I can trigger validation on Radio buttons and check boxes on change/blur?
Here is my sample code for 'onfocusout'

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
        if( $(element).attr('name') ) { 
            this.element(element);              
            app.BlurValidation(element);
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
}
```

I did find similar question but the following solution is not showing result at my end.

```
$('#check').on('blur', function() {
    $("#myForm").validate().element( this );
});
```

Comment: Describe **in detail** what you are talking about, and show enough code to construct a demo.  By default, `onfocusout` works **exactly** the same for `radio` & `checkbox` groups as it does for `text` inputs.  See:  https://jsfiddle.net/bagk7spf/  - So what exactly are you trying to do and where is it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparky is right, it works with radio and checkbox. You should check your codes again. One thing I learned when I faced same issue was not to use `visibility: hidden;` CSS property for radio or checkbox in case you are trying to style them, instead use `opacity:0;`

The validation plugin will consider the field as hidden field if it has the CSS property of `visibility: hidden;` and hence will ignore it for `onfocusout`

Hope my experience might come in handy for your case

Comment: same problem :)